# Rails 5: How to save uniq element in Array of Hash get from API's response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm try to use API from a logistics company in my country to `Get District List`, `Calculate Shipping Fee` and `Create Shipping Order`
`Get District List` response format is like this:

```
data:
  [{ 
    ProvinceID: X,
    ProvinceName: Y,
    DistrictID: A1,
    DistrictName: B1
  },
  { 
    ProvinceID: X,
    ProvinceName: Y,
    DistrictID: A2,
    DistrictName: B2
  }]
```

How I can save uniq `ProvinceID` and `ProvinceName` to database?
I'm try the solution in other `topic` on `stackoverflow`:

```
 @province = []
 @province = @response['data'].map{
|item| item['ProvinceName']
 }.uniq
```

It's worked fine, but only `ProvinceName` saved.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Array#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-values_at)
 to generate an array to uniq by.

```
@response['data'].uniq{ |s| s.values_at(:ProvinceID, :ProvinceName) }
```

Comment: The result just show first element. Then i delete values_at method,  luckily its work. Thank you very much. Another question:  when getting response, how can i save it to `District` and `Province` model at the same time? I know nested attribute but i dont know how to do it exactly

Comment: Can you please describe or elaborate your need what exactly you want, so I can help correctly. :)